# Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit is showing only 3.2 gib ram

Tags: 14.04, ram

My ubuntu installation is 64 bit. I have read about 4gb ram issue but this is 32 bit problem. I have checked it's showing 3.2 Gib ram in two slots instead of 4 Gib.

[image]

It's showing only 3.2 gib:

[image]

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C video`:

```
*-display
 description: VGA compatible controller 
 irq:27 memory:fea80000-feafffff ioport:dc00(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe900000-fe9fffffproduct: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller 
 vendor: Intel Corporation 
 physical id: 2
 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
  version: 10
 width: 32 bits
 clock: 33MHz 
 capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
 configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 
 resources: irq:27 memory:fea80000-feafffff ioport:dc00(size=8)memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe900000-fe9fffff
```

Output of LC_ALL=C lspci -v | grep -EA10 "3D|VGA" | grep 'prefetchable'

```
LC_ALL=C lspci -v | grep -EA10 "3D|VGA" | grep 'prefetchable'
    Memory at fea80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fe900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
```

Comment: Probably your video card takes some RAM.

Comment: Did it ever work and show more RAM? How much RAM are you expecting to see? Does the motherboard manufacturer say what its memory limit is? Your swap of 2GB is too small even for 4GB RAM. Do you have more than 2 physical memory slots?

Comment: I have 4gb ram in 2 slots. According to motherboard manufacturer 4gb is max limit.

Comment: What is your video card model?

Comment: Find it with the `sudo lshw -C video` command.

Comment: @luchonacho this is not showing any RAM usage.

resources: irq:27 memory:fea80000-feafffff ioport:dc00(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe900000-fe9fffff

Comment: @dadexix86 
sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       ( description: VGA compatible controller )
       ( product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller )
       ( vendor: Intel Corporation )
       ( physical id: 2 )
       ( bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 )
       ( version: 10 )
       ( width: 32 bits )
       ( clock: 33MHz )
       ( capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom )
       ( configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 )
       ( resources: above comment)

Comment: All these brackets are weird around the output. Are you sure to be on Ubuntu? Attach the output of `LC_ALL=C lspci -v | grep -EA10 "3D|VGA" | grep 'prefetchable' ` to your question please.

Comment: for what it's worth: I have an old laptop with for 4gb of RAM. I get exactly the same responses as you in the terminal. In system monitor however I have 3.8GiB RAM and 3.9 GiB Swap.

Comment: @dadexix86 I have attached output of LC_ALL=C lspci -v | grep -EA10 "3D|VGA" | grep 'prefetchable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling "Memory Remap Feature" in BIOS can fix this problem.
After enabling this my 3.2 Gib RAM issue is fixed.

Press F2 key during computer start for BIOS setting.(key maybe different, depends on motherboard)

BIOS -> ADVANCED SETTING -> MEMORY REMAP FEATURE.

Click on image links for detail.

[Now OS is displaying 3.9 Gib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trnFW.png)

[BIOS MEMORY REMAP FEATURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehY2h.png)